# Python & Selenium: Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to using selenium with python for web scraping. The webpage I am trying to scrape data from has href elements within a specific nav class. I need to click in the EXAMPLE3, but i cant find a class name or id.

```
<nav class"nav-main">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="topMain"><li class="dropdown">
        ::before
        <li class="dropdown">
           <a>EXAMPLE1<a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
           <a>EXAMPLE2<a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
           <a>EXAMPLE3<a>
        </li>
           :after
      </ul>
   </nav>
```

Thank you!

Comment: show us the code that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Selenium’s find_elements_by_css_selector() method, you can fetch all of the elements with a common class name and click on any one of them. Here’s a couple of lines of code that should guide you in the right direction:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("LOCAL_PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER")
driver.get("YOUR_URL")

content = driver.page_source

third_element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('nav ul li.dropdown a')[2]

third_element.click()
```

Alternatively, it might help to get a look at the following article (the link should get you to the ‘How to Extract Statically Loaded Content Using Selenium’ section) as it expands on the same idea of using Selenium to access clickable elements: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-2/#how-to-extract-statically-loaded-content-using-selenium